# # Power BI Divide by distinct value for a group by

Tags: powerbi, dax

Table1

| Region | Subregion | DataID | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North Central | Missouri | 12042022 | 123000 |
| North Central | Minnesota | 12052022 | 170000 |
| North Central | North Dakota | 10042022 | 234000 |
| Northeast | New York | 08042022 | 500000 |
| Northeast | New Jersey | 12052022 | 578000 |
| Southwest | Nevada | 12032022 | 679000 |
| Southwest | Arizona | 10032022 | 654000 |

DimDate

| DataID | Period | NumofWeeks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12052022 | 2022_05 | 5 |
| 10042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12052022 | 2022_05 | 5 |
| 08042022 | 2022_04 | 4 |
| 12032022 | 2022_03 | 4 |
| 10032022 | 2022_03 | 4 |

I want to Divide the count of records per region by NumofWeeks

I tried

```
Divide per region week = MROUND(DIVIDE(COUNT('table1'[Region]), DISTINCT(DimDate[NumofWeeks])),1)
```

Works but only if I filter the Matrix by just one Period for more I have the message
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected

I appreciate your help Thank you

Comment: `DISTINCT()` function returns a table ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/distinct-function-dax)).  
This is a reason why you get such error.  
What are you expecting to get as a result of your measure? Your request has no sense to me: why do you want to divide number of not-null rows in a *Region* column to a number of weeks in months?

Comment: For each Period there are a specific number of weeks (integer) and I want the total Count per region divided by the number of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have unique DimDate[Period]-DimDate[NumofWeeks] linked values then you can try this suggetion.

```
Divide per region week = 

VAR TotalCountPerRegion = CountRows('Table1')
VAR tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod=
    SUMMARIZE(
        DimDate
        ,DimDate[Period]
        ,DimDate[NumofWeeks]
    )

VAR SuMOfWeeksInPeriod = SUMX(tblNumOfWeeksInPeriod,DimDate[NumofWeeks])

RETURN
    MROUND(
            DIVIDE(
                TotalCountPerRegion 
                ,SuMOfWeeksInPeriod
            )
            ,1
    )
```

Comment: why do you use COUNTROWS(DISTINCT()) while there is a DISTINCTCOUNT() function?

Comment: There are no reason for COUNTROWS, exept better explanation, as for me

Comment: It didn't work because what I wanted is  a matrix with rows Period and columns Region with the measure Total count per region by period divided by the number of weeks, the number of weeks is the same per  Period

Comment: Hi, you can try this one. I didn't check the syntax, hope it works )

Comment: Thank you works can I create a new measure with the sum of "Divide per region week"  for Northeast and  Southeast is it possible?

Comment: No problem. Frist yuo can add the slicer. If you want to get this measure and then the measure that shows you exactly  for Northeast and Southeast then open a new question, and let me know that you did it.

Comment: @ofeliajesus I saw the new question. At the moment I'm little bit overloaded with my current  tasks. So, If the issue will not be solved within a week I'll they to help you. If somebody will solve it don't forget to mark the answer.